# How to increase wait time for Google Cloud Tasks?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-tasks

I am creating a lot of tasks to be processed in Cloud Tasks, but some of them are failing due to lack of available resources (instances). Please see the image below:

[image: image1]

As you can see, the average time Google waits before throwing http 500 error is 10 seconds, and sometimes, less than 10ms is enough to throw http 500. This queue has auto-retry set, so, eventually all tasks are executed, but the error remains.

Is there a way to increase this wait time? I don't care waiting 5 minutes to process the task, I just want to minimize the amount of errors like this on my logging panel.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question not too long ago and didn't get any helpful answers.  I don't know if you can increase the rate of creating tasks.

A few things to try:

- Batch tasks together -- Instead of creating 10 tasks can you create one task that does the work of all 10?
- Serial tasks -- Create a first task that does work and then creates a second task.  The second task does work and then creates a third task, etc.
- Pull queues might allow for a higher task creation rate.  Not sure about that.